# php sort data according to 2nd table

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have two tables: Table 1 and Table 2

[image]

I need to sort the data as shown in Table View.

I have already taken:

```
foreach($Table1 as $row1 )
{
    foreach($Table2 as $row2 )
    {
          if($row1->id == $row2->selected_id)
          {
                  show??
          }
    }

}
```

please do not worry about queries: it is taken care of real issue is:

there is only one problem: Table 1 is generated from 20 different function and collects to Table 1. and user selects which they want to view by selecting. so, if there is total of 7 rows and user selects 3, so data will be sorted showing 3 rows selected at first rows and rest after the 3 rows.

is this the right way to do it? or is there much easier way
I am using MySQL

please help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your [additional question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622031/php-data-sorted-according-to-array-no-queries), it seems that you **don't want** to use MySQL for that, and that your user selection is in fact an array like this one:

```
$filter = [ 3, 4, 7, 8 ];
```

Filter the original `$Table1` array by using `array_reduce`. With this method you obtain an array (`$filtered`) with user selection in element 0 and other values in element 1:

```
$filtered = array_reduce
(
    $Table1,
    function( $carry, $item ) use( $filter )
    {
        $index = !in_array( $item['id'], $filter );
        $carry[$index][] = $item;
        return $carry;
    },
    [ [], [] ]
);
```

Then, merge `$filtered` data with `call_user_func_array`:

```
$result = call_user_func_array( 'array_merge', $filtered );
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => C
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => D
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => G
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => H
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => A
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => B
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => E
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => F
        )
)
```

Comment: This seems to be correct, but cant seem to figure it out how to implement it.
kindly can you show me a working example???

Comment: Above is a working example. `$Table1` is your original array, `$filter` is your user selection, `$result` is the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a single query, no need to loop over both tables afterwards

```
   Select t1.id, t1.name
     From Table1 t1
Left Join Table2 t2 On t1.id = t2.selected_id
 Order By t2.id, t1.id
```

Comment: there is only one problem: Table 1 is generated from 20 different function and collects to Table 1. and user selects which they want to view by selecting. so, if there is total of 7 rows and user selects 3, so data will be sorted showing 3 rows seleted at first rows and rest after the 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an effective SQL query to get the final table immediately like so:

**Query1:**

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.name
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1
ON t2.id=t1.id;
```

This would output the first 4 rows and then:

**Query2:**

```
SELECT id, name
FROM t1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2);
```

Would output the last 4 rows, after that just do a UNION:

**Final query:**

```
Query1 UNION Query2;
```

**Explicitly:**

```
(SELECT t2.id, t2.name
        FROM t2
        INNER JOIN t1
        ON t2.id=t1.id)
UNION
(SELECT id, name
        FROM t1
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2));
```

**Bit more compact:**

```
(SELECT t2.*
            FROM t2
            INNER JOIN t1
            ON t2.id=t1.id)
    UNION
    (SELECT *
            FROM t1
            WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2));
```

Comment: there is only one problem: Table 1 is generated from 20 different function and collects to Table 1. and user selects which they want to view by selecting. so, if there is total of 7 rows and user selects 3, so data will be sorted showing 3 rows seleted at first rows and rest after the 3 rows.

Comment: Isn't sorting the selected rows first and then the remaining ones that you want?

Comment: exacly! but it can not be done by joing: because table 1 is not a mySQL table. but table2  is a table in mySQL whihc is collected from table1 with id's

Answer (score 0):

You can do below query.

```
Select t1.* from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1 on t2.selected_id = t1.id order by t2.id
UNION
Select t1.* from table1 t1 where t1.id NOT IN ( select t2.id from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1 on t2.selected_id = t1.id ) order by t1.id
```

Comment: there is only one problem: Table 1 is generated from 20 different function and collects to Table 1. and user selects which they want to view by selecting. so, if there is total of 7 rows and user selects 3, so data will be sorted showing 3 rows seleted at first rows and rest after the 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union to show the selected rows first then the not selected ones next, combined with **(where in ) and (where not in) clauses**  next here is the query:

```
(select t1.id, t1.name from table1 t1 where t1.id 
in (select t2.selected_id from table2 t2)) union
(select t1.id , t1.name from table1 t1 where t1.id 
not in (select t2.selected_id from table2 t2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use at query : Order By field(). In the field() function second table data as string comma separated.